# Standard deviation of input numbers with JAVA

Tags: java, average, addition

I am new to this place and in need of serious help. After spending 6 hours trying to figure out this, I am going insane and need help. Here is the question i am assigned.

1. Create the StandardDeviation project. Write a java program that reads a set of double data values. When all the values have been read, print out the count of the values, the average and the standard deviation.

I cannot find any commands that allow for a group of entered numbers at once and be read by JAVA. Could someone please help me get started or point to somewhere where i can find relative problems  or examples. Thank you very much. All i know is that it supposed to start with 
while (in.hasNextDouble())

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: @PhilippSemenenko - at the risk of stating the obvious, this is doubtless covered in your lecture notes and/or your recommended text books.  And your lecturer should have told you where to find the Javadocs online and so on.

Comment: This specifically wasnt covered unfortunately. We were only told how to do it while the user inputs one number at a time, and then prompted to continue. We didnt cover how to record multiple numbers at once from the user like "2 4 10 49" etc However, it can be as many numbers as the user wants.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is homework.

You're going to want to look at [java.util.Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), it will let you do `while( Scanner.hasNextDouble() )` which you can then sum. You're also going to want to keep track of all the numbers so you should take a look at [java.util.ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Note: to use `ArrayList` properly you'll have to use the Double class, which can be treated almost exactly like a double primitive, or you can use arrays instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. It can read input data and you can repeatedly call hasNextDouble and nextDouble on it to pull out the data.

Comment: If it helps. this is what i have so far. 
package standarddeviation;
import java.util.*;
public class StandardDeviation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double deviation = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        }
    }
}

Comment: That code definitely will help, but it will be more helpful within the body of the question. Please put it there *and add the appropriate code formatting tags*. Then everyone can help you out even more.

Answer (score 0):

From javaman (http://www.daniweb.com/members/javaman2/471995) I find a solution. It looks like the Scanner class provides capabilities in this area also.